# Why do DVD drives needs a region to be selected?

Tags: dvd

Why do DVD drives needs a region to be selected? And why is there a limited number of Country/Region to be changed? Note that the same applied to some Dial-up Modems.

Comment: This applies to appliances, Windows, Mac OSX, and Linux. Removed the OSX tag because of that. Removed the Driver tag as it is not a driver issue. Removed the MAC tag, as that's about Media Address Code, not Mac OSX. Hope this helps

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_region_code

Answer (score 4):

It is for DRM. Different regions have different licensing.

I wasn't aware this happened for OS X. It surely does not in Linux.

Comment: I see now what you mean. There was a bit of a misunderstanding, sorry. The OP anyway just brought it as another example; they didn't ask about modems specifically.